# Why cannot $\frac{0}{0}$ (indeterminate element) be added to a Field extension to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Why cannot $\frac{0}{0}$ be added to a field extension to complex field $\Bbb C$? I know the complex field $\Bbb C$ is closed. But can we define additional elements such as $1*\frac{0}{0}$,  $2*\frac{0}{0}$, $i*\frac{0}{0}$ and extend $\Bbb C$ and study its properties?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I'm guessing that OP wants to define $0/0$ as a separate element. But I still feel like that would be fraught with issues.

Comment: Argh, thanks, I need to think more carefully for a second. An element $\frac{0}{0}$ would at least need to satisfy $\frac{0}{0} \cdot 0 = 0$ to justify the notation, but $z \cdot 0 =0$ in the field of formal Laurent series $\mathbb{C}((z))$, which is a perfectly good field extension of $\mathbb{C}$. I guess the million dollar question for the OP is: do you want $w \cdot \frac{0}{0} = \frac{w \cdot 0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$ to hold for any $w \in \mathbb{C}$, for some $w$, or for no $w$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić it seems galling at first but $\frac 00$ would have the trivial property that $\frac 00* 0 = 0$ and nothing else.  I think zambawithkolbasa's answer is correct.  We can do this but it doesn't "mean" anything.  If we let $w*\frac 00 = \frac{w*0}0$ then $\frac 00 = 0$.  But we could just as easily say $w*\frac 00=w$ and $\frac 00 = 1$. heck for that matter we could say $w*\frac 00 = 2w$ and $\frac 00 = 2$.  What we *can't* do I think is define any $\frac 10$ or any $0*w = k \ne 0$.

Comment: what would be the multiplicative inverse of $0/0$?

Comment: You might be interested in [wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1370214/124095.

Comment: The answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1370342/124095 is relevant here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elucidating me. I was merely trying to find out if these "indeterminate holes" in continuous, possibly multivariate functions could be plugged by including $\frac{0}{0}$ in the Complex field. If we could then we could find the "uber Field" which has truly continuous functions

Comment: The Complex field extensions, if definable, can be for Cantor's Transfinite numbers as well. This would possibly pave the way for computing problems such as P=NP to be addressed as I strongly feel that these sets could have transfinite cardinality and proving P = NP could be merely proving that that the cardinality are either equal or not...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add that as an element and get $C\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$, the field of rational functions over $C$. That is what you obtain by adding an "indeterminate element" to a field.

The question is if you want to require any relations between $\frac{0}{0}$ or its powers and other elements of $C$.

Some people prefer to call it $x$ if no other relations are required.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I think it is meaningful to have relations of $\frac{0}{0}$ with other elements impossible with the traditional Field operators i.e "*" and "+" under traditional sense. The question is, whether there is an operator that can work with all elements and still can extend to indeterminate. I know it is silly but I don't know if the "operator" defined can be a conglomeration or composition of the numerical operators(+, *, \, etc.)  performed in certain order on the two elements that finally results in a closed Group( it's no longer a Field in the traditional sense) with Inverse.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $\frac00$ to be an independent symbol, you can adjoin it to a field. As noted by zambawithkolbasa, this would give the same field as just adjoining an indeterminate, $x$.

On the other hand, if you want $\frac00$ to behave like it looks like it should notationally, you will run into problems:
For instance, in a field, by $\frac{a}{b}$, we mean $a\cdot b^{-1}$, but then $\frac00=0\cdot 0^{-1}$, and this is meaningless since $0$ in a field does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Also, the inverse of $\frac00$ notationally should be the reciprocal, $\frac00$.  But then $\left(\frac00\right) ^2=1$.  However then in your extension field, the polynomial $x^2=1$ has more than two roots ($1, -1, \frac00$).  This is even true in characteristic $2$ where $1$ is a double root.